# findElement always returns position -1 for DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a document which has the following example text:

"I want to remove this {{image1}}, but not this image2"

I need to remove image1 (actual image), but not image2. The catch is that image1 is not always there. So what I do is:

1. I search for {{ - `resultStart = body.findText("\{\{")`
2. I search for the first image after {{ - `images = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE,resultStart)`

The problem is that `images.getEndOffsetInclusive()` always returns "-1" so I cannot confirm that the image found is the first image and not the second one. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I created a test doc with This is {{image1}} followed by an inline image.  The following script will find the image.

```
function findImage() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let element = body.findText("{{image1}}");
    element = element.getElement().getNextSibling();
    console.log(element.toString());
    element.removeFromParent();
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
7:51:32 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:51:34 AM  Info    InlineImage
7:51:33 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works partially in case image1 is in a different paragraph from image2. However if they are in the same paragraph and image 1 is missing, then image2 gets deleted. Example:

"I want to remove this {{ }}, but not this image2".

Would remove image2.

Comment: I thought you had 2 images.  I don't think you can do what you want.  `body.findText()` returns a RangeElement which is the loation of text within a Paragraph.  If both images are in the same paragraph it will get the first of the 2 because its a Sibling.  If there is only 1 image then it will get that Sibling.  I think your question is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I mentioned this in my original post: I need to remove image1 (actual image), but not image2. The catch is that image1 is not always there.